# How to pass the id in stored procedure which coming from DrillDown

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am using charting and making the bar to drill down and display the values ,I want to know ,How to pass the id in stored procedure which comming from drilldown
Note: Please look at the code in "elseif"
Here Is  My code

C# Part:

```
SeriesCollection SC = new SeriesCollection();
    DataEngine de = new DataEngine();




    de.DataFields = "xAxis=Empname,yAxis=TotalLeave,ToolTip=LeaveType";
    Chart.XAxis.Label.Text = "Department/Employees";
    Chart.TempDirectory = "temp";
    Chart.Debug = true;
    Chart.JS.Enabled = true; 
    de.ConnectionString = conString;
    if (Request.QueryString["ddLevel"] == null )
    {
        Chart.Title = "ABSENTEE REPORT";
        txtstart.Visible = true;
        txtend.Visible = true;
        Button3.Visible = true;
        Button2.Visible = true;
        de.StoredProcedure = "AbsenteeReport2";
        de.ConnectionString = conString;
        de.ParameterCollection.Clear();
        de.AddParameter("@Startdate", txtstart.Text, FieldType.Date);
        de.AddParameter("@Enddate", txtend.Text, FieldType.Date);
        de.DataFields = "Xaxis=DeptName,Yaxis=LeaveCount,url=Deptname";
        Chart.Series.ConnectionString = conString;
        Chart.Series.StoredProcedure = "AbsenteeReport2";
        Chart.Series.ParameterCollection.Clear();
        Chart.Series.AddParameter("@Startdate", txtstart.Text, FieldType.Date);
        Chart.Series.AddParameter("@Enddate", txtend.Text, FieldType.Date);
        Chart.DataBind();
        Chart.Visible = true;
        Chart.SeriesCollection.Add(SC);
        Chart.Visible = true;
        SC = de.GetSeries();


        foreach (Series s in SC)
        {
            foreach (Element el in s.Elements)
            {
                el.URL = "?id=" + el.URL + "&ddLevel=2";
            }
        }
        Chart.SeriesCollection.Add(SC);
```

}

```
    else if (Request.QueryString["ddLevel"] == "2")
    {
        Chart.Title = "ABSENTEE REPORT";
       // de.SqlStatement = "Select Empname,TotalLeave,LeaveType From Charting32 Where Deptname = '" + Request.QueryString["id"] + "'";
        de.StoredProcedure = "AbsenteeReport1 Where Deptname = '" + Request.QueryString["id"] + "'";
        de.ConnectionString = conString;
        de.ParameterCollection.Clear();
        de.AddParameter("@Startdate", txtstart.Text, FieldType.Date);
        de.AddParameter("@Enddate", txtend.Text, FieldType.Date);
        de.DataFields = "xAxis=Empname,yAxis=TotalLeave,ToolTip=LeaveType";
        SC = de.GetSeries();
        Chart.DefaultElement.ToolTip = "<block>Type: <block hAlign='left'>%yvalue<row>";
        txtstart.Visible = false;
        txtend.Visible = false;
        Button3.Visible = false;
        Button2.Visible = false;
        Chart.Height = 550;

        foreach (Series s in SC)
        {
            foreach (Element el in s.Elements)
            {
                el.ToolTip = "<block>LeaveType:<block>".Replace(":", System.Environment.NewLine) + el.ToolTip.Replace(",", System.Environment.NewLine);     
            } 
        }
        Chart.SeriesCollection.Add(SC);
    }
```

My Sp :

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[AbsenteeReport1](@Startdate DateTime,@Enddate Datetime)
as
Begin
With CTE as (
    SELECT   EmployeeDetails.Empname,
             DepartmentDetails.Deptname ,
             LeaveApplication.LeaveType,
             Sum(LeaveApplication.NoOfDays) As TotalLeave 
    FROM DepartmentDetails 
    Inner JOIN EmployeeDetails on EmployeeDetails.DeptID = DepartmentDetails.DeptID
    INNER JOIN LeaveApplication On EmployeeDetails.EmpID = LeaveApplication.EmpID
    WHERE     LeaveApplication.LeaveFromDate >=@Startdate 
          AND LeaveApplication.LeaveFromDate <=@Enddate 
          AND  EmployeeDetails.Status=0 
          AND  LeaveApplication.leavetype not in ('Forgot Access Card','Permission','Work from Home',
                                          'Holiday Allowance/Weekend Allowance','On Duty','Night Shift Allowance') 
          AND LeaveApplication.LeaveStatus<>'Rejected'
    GROUP BY     LeaveApplication.EmpID ,
             DepartmentDetails.Deptname,
             EmployeeDetails.Empname,
             LeaveApplication.LeaveType
         )
select EmpName, Deptname, stuff ((
    select ',' + LeaveType+'-'+ cast(TotalLeave as varchar(5)) from CTE where EmpName = t.EmpName and Deptname = t.Deptname for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') as LeaveType,
    Sum(TotalLeave) as TotalLeave
from CTE t
group by EmpName, Deptname

End
```

Comment: Same as you passed textbox vale,  de.AddParameter("@Startdate", dropdown1.selectedvalue, FieldType.Date);

Comment: Hi Sir I din't use any dropdown in this sir ,When I click on the Bar in char,It gets DRILLDOWN.Pls see my code in "if loop" where i hve passed id

Comment: The items that get returned are in the SELECT.   So just add LeaveApplication.EmpID to the select.

Comment: Can you please Send some code :)

Comment: See the Way I have Harcorded it

Comment: @jdweng It Works When I am Hardcoding

Comment: I don't see any hardcoded id.